# How do I fix error with MassTransit

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I am trying to use MassTransit, I installed it using nuget and am just using their base example:

[Quick start guide](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html)

When I run this code I get an exceptions (with the inner exceptions listed):

- "An exception was thrown during service bus creation"
- "Failed to create the bus service: SubscriptionRouterService"
- "msmq-pgm://235.109.116.115:7784/test_queue_control_subscriptions => An exception was thrown during Send"
- "Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length"

Is there any help anyone can give me on getting past this error?

Notes:
MSMQ is installed, and I've used it for WCF based MSMQ services.
All the queues look like they are being created in MSMQ before that error line

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone been able to fix this?

Comment: I'd recommend moving some of the code highlighting the issue into the question, as right now, you have a link to an external resource which could go down at any time.  I.E. there's no *context*.

Answer (score 5):

We left out the following line to make the Getting Started sample to work:

`sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();`

Comment: worked for me, too. Make sense since the queue being created is a private one.

Comment: you should be using sbc.UseMsmq instead, since usemulticast is now obsolete